# Fleury's algorithm for oriented graph

Tags: algorithm, graph

I am going to implement an algorithm for finding an Eulerian path in an oriented graph and am deciding which algorithm would be the best.

I have found [Fleury's algorithm](http://www.austincc.edu/powens/+Topics/HTML/05-6/05-6.html) which seems neat but all the examples I have seen consider only non-oriented graphs. Does anyone know if this will work with an oriented graph?

It seems to me that adjacency list can be specified for every single vertex so it should work but I am not 100% sure.

What if there are paralel edges in the graph?

Thanks for any answer!

Comment: The Eulerian circuit was proven for graphs with nodes with even numbers of edges, but even here means both inbound/outbound.  Certainly you only need either inbound or outbound at each edge taken (all might not be),  But a directed graph might not have outbound (or inbound) along an edge when needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a directed graph the inbound and outbound edge must be the same:http://www8.cs.umu.se/kurser/TDBAfl/VT06/algorithms/BOOK/BOOK4/NODE165.HTM